# Django: Extent with snippets or better solution

Tags: python, django

I have the following template:

```
{% extends "account/base.html" %}

{% load i18n %}
{% load account %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block head_title %}{% trans "Password Reset" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-8">
      <h1>Reset your password</h1>
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      {% include "account/snippets/already_logged_in.html" %}
      {% endif %}

      <p>{% trans "Forgotten your password? Enter your e-mail address below, and we'll send you an e-mail allowing you to reset it." %}</p>

      <form method="POST" action="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}" class="password_reset">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form|crispy }}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Reset My Password</button>
      </form>

      <p><em>{% blocktrans %}Please contact us if you have any trouble resetting your password.{% endblocktrans %}</em></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

account/base.html contains this here:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

base.html then contains  tags etc. I am currently struggling with finding the best solution while considering DRY. In my template I have written:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
     <div class="col-8">
     [more text]
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have several of these templates and in each of them I am currently writing the same  ... I am now wondering is the right solution to include these opening / closing div-tags in two files and then add

```
{% include "div-open.html" %}
[more text] 
{% include "div-closing.html" %}
```

Or is there any better solution to this? It doesn't feel right, that's why I am asking you now how you would solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I depends if HTML repetition should be considered as DRY violation. I you have custom form fields which you want to include, than having `{% include 'simple_custom_field.html' with field=form.some_fied %}` where

**simple_custom_field.html**

```
<input
    type="{{ field.field.widget.input_type }}"
    class="form-control {{ field.field.widget.attrs.class }} {{ class }}"
    id="{{ field.id_for_label }}"
    name="{{ field.html_name }}"
    placeholder="{{ field.label }}"
    {% if field.value is not None %} value="{{ field.value }}"{% endif %}>
```

or like that...

is good idea, or you can render whole form like that also if you have long blocks or separate blocks of HTML in multiple files, then go for it. But its bad idea for including simple and fundamental parts of HTML. **It should be transparent for the programmer**.

If you want to do it another way, there are ways how to add custom template tags and "modify" the language you write templates in.
Here is docs how to do it: [Writing custom template tags | Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags)